# I want to create top inner curved background like below image? how to do with css

Tags: html, css

I want to create top inner curved background like orange colour part shown in below pic.
how to do with css?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEJ8B.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You should apply border-radius: Xpx to the white part.
If you want to apply only to the bottom part, you should use this:

```
border-bottom-right-radius: Xpx;
border-bottom-left-radius: Xpx;
```

Modify the X value to the amount of pixels you want the curve.

Comment: no! its not same as I mentioned in above link image

Answer (score 0):

```css
#circle {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
}

#cir {
  position: absolute;
  top: -400px;
  left: -150px;
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
<div id="cir"></div>
```

Comment: what is the code only for orange part?

Comment: Actually, white part is the one helping in making the effect, #cir is the white part and #circle is the orange part.